# How to avoid point cloud waiveness of intel d415 at 2meter distance

Tags: point-cloud-library, realsense, ransac

A understand stereo algorithm provides more error as we move towards more distant ranges.  What i am experiencing is the point cloud waiveness is very high at 2m.  On my experiment Minimum z and Maximum Z  of a plane at 2meter varies by 10 cm.

I am trying to plane fit a Ransac on my cloud, but the Ransac always differs around 1cm for the same scene at different instances.  How to overcome this and provide depth data.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Mostly ,it is not possible because of the noise in depth. You can try applying post processing filters on depth frame, it reduces the waviness but might cause other errors depending on your use case.

Comment: That's the limitation of D415, get other RGBD camera such as L515. If you can't, try to implement this postprocessing https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/depth-post-processing